# Get weights data from a benchmarked pallet

Tags: pallet, benchmarking, frame

Is there a way to get some informations for an already benchmarked pallet on the weights like the minimum and maximum weights that can be used for a function (worst case/best case) ?

Comment: Do you want to use benchmarks someone has created for another project? Or do you want to access the weights in your code?

Comment: None, technically all is setup in my code, I just wanted to know the way to extract the weights data from my weights.rs file, cause I wanna compute the maximum and minimum fees a function will use if we call it in multiple case